# Button click event only works when page is reloaded or alert in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that a couple of buttons I have on my HTML page only work when there is an `alert` in the function of the event, or when I navigate to another page and then back to the home page. From other similar problems I've read about, it seems as though the home page is attempting to finish some task and that the alert is buying it more time. However, I am not sure that is true in my case.

I have a Javascript file `actions.js` that is loaded by the HTML page in the header as a source. The file is as follows (only showing relevant code) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //This function only works with an alert before the Ajax call or when page is reloaded
    $("button[name='delete_deck']").click(function() {
        var id = this.id;

        $.ajax({
            url: "delete_decks.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: {selection:JSON.stringify(id)},
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

    //This function is for a button on the same page, but works fine without the alert or reloading the page
    $("#study").click(function() {
        var selection = getDeckSelections();

        if(selection.length > 0) {
            //Get the selected side of the card
            var selected_side = $('input[name=side_selection]:checked', '#side_selection_form').val();

            //Store the selected side in session storage
            sessionStorage.setItem("selected_side", selected_side);

            //Ajax call to get cards from database
            $.ajax({
                url: "get_cards.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {selection:JSON.stringify(selection)},
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    json = JSON.parse(data);
                    //Store the cards in session storage
                    sessionStorage.setItem("cards", JSON.stringify(json));
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: is this page contain dynamic html markups name like 'delete_deck'?

Comment: @Prageeth yes, the `delete_deck` buttons are dynamically generated, while the `study` button is not

Comment: @Prageeth the issue only occurs with dynimcally generated buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(document).on('click',"button[name='delete_deck']",function() {
    var id = this.id;

    $.ajax({
        url: "delete_decks.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {selection:JSON.stringify(id)},
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
});
```